# In version 13, WSTPServer cannot execute LaunchKernels[]

Tags: parallelization, mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access, kernel-startup

When I execute LaunchKernels[] or Kernels[], I get the following errors.The output of Kernels[] is {}.
[image]
"WSTPServer" is not among the known evaluation environments
{Session, RemoteSession, FrontEnd, Subkernel, WebEvaluation, WebAPI,
Scheduled, Script, Kernel

In version 12, it works well and I use it to run the program on the server. Now it's fine to run on a single core, for example $MachineName.But parallel computing doesn't work anymore. For example, ParallelMap[Sin, Range[10]] does not work.
[image]